# How can we use lagom's Read-side processor with Dgraph?

Tags: java, microservices, lagom, dgraph

I am a newbie to lagom and dgraph. And I got stuck to how to use lagom's read-side processor with **Dgraph**. Just to give you an idea following is the code which uses Cassandra with lagom.

```
import akka.NotUsed;
import com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.ServiceCall;
import com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.cassandra.CassandraSession;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;
public class FriendServiceImpl implements FriendService {

private final CassandraSession cassandraSession;

@Inject
public FriendServiceImpl(CassandraSession cassandraSession) {
    this.cassandraSession = cassandraSession;
}

//Implement your service method here

}
```

Comment: Well, does `com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.dgraph` exist as a package?

Comment: @cricket_007 Till now, I haven't come across any such package that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagom does not provide out-of-the-box support for Dgraph. If you have to use Lagom's Read-Side processor with Dgraph, then you have to use Lagom's [Generic Read Side support](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/ReadSide.html#Query-the-Read-Side-Database). Like this:

```
/**
 * Read side processor for Dgraph.
 */
public class FriendEventProcessor extends ReadSideProcessor<FriendEvent> {
    private static void createModel() {
        //TODO: Initialize schema in Dgraph
    }

    @Override
    public ReadSideProcessor.ReadSideHandler<FriendEvent> buildHandler() {
        return new ReadSideHandler<FriendEvent>() {
            private final Done doneInstance = Done.getInstance();

            @Override
            public CompletionStage<Done> globalPrepare() {
                createModel();
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(doneInstance);
            }

            @Override
            public CompletionStage<Offset> prepare(final AggregateEventTag<FriendEvent> tag) {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Offset.NONE);
            }

            @Override
            public Flow<Pair<FriendEvent, Offset>, Done, ?> handle() {
                return Flow.<Pair<FriendEvent, Offset>>create()
                        .mapAsync(1, eventAndOffset -> {
                                    if (eventAndOffset.first() instanceof FriendCreated) {
                                        //TODO: Add Friend in Dgraph;
                                    }

                                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(doneInstance);
                                }
                        );
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public PSequence<AggregateEventTag<FriendEvent>> aggregateTags() {
        return FriendEvent.TAG.allTags();
    }
}
```

For `FriendEvent.TAG.allTags()`, you have to add following code in `FriendEvent` interface:

```
int NUM_SHARDS = 20;

  AggregateEventShards<FriendEvent> TAG =
          AggregateEventTag.sharded(FriendEvent.class, NUM_SHARDS);

  @Override
  default AggregateEventShards<FriendEvent> aggregateTag() {
    return TAG;
  }
```

I hope this helps!